# Finding free variables in echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm practicing these problems where you get it into rref and then identify if its empty set, a point, a line, a plane. I came across a problem like this...

$x+2y-z=0$

$2x+y-z=1$

After getting the augmented matrix and doing rref I get...

$x+1/2y-1/2z=1/2$

$y-1/3z=-1/3$

Is $y$ considered a free variable? At first I think it is, because there is a $1/2y$ when in rref. Though I'm not 100% sure and wanted to check. If there are two free variables of $y$ and $z$ then its a plane, if there is only $z$ then its a line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduction goes as follows
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -3 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets R_2-2R_1
\\[4px]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1/3 & -1/3
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets -\tfrac{1}{3}R_2
\\[4px]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1/3 & 2/3 \\
0 & 1 & -1/3 & -1/3
\end{array}\right]
&& R_1\gets R_1-2R_2
\end{align}
whereby the solutions can be written as
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}z\\[4px]
y=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}z
\end{cases}
This says $z$ *can* be taken as a free variable, but it's a convention and also $y$ could be used as free variable (even $x$): just write the system as
\begin{cases}
x-z+2y=0\\[4px]
2x-z+y=1
\end{cases}
and the reduction would be
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -3 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets R_2-2R_1
\\[4px]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -3 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&& R_1\gets R_1+R_2
\end{align}
whereby the solutions could be written as
\begin{cases}
x=1+y \\[4px]
z=1+3y
\end{cases}

In any case there is just *one* free variable, notwithstanding how you write the solutions. This is because the incomplete matrix has rank $2$ and the number of free variables is “number of unknowns minus the rank”.

Note that, apart from possible errors in your computation, you didn't reach the *reduced* row echelon form, which requires having zeros below and also *above* the leading $1$'s.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one free variable, but which one it is will depend on how you work out the system.

You can consider $y$ as a free variable if you write the solution set as $\{(1+y,y,1+3y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Equally well, we can consider $z$ as free variable by writing the solution set as $\{(\frac{z+2}{3},\frac{z-1}{3},z):z\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Or we can consider $x$ as free variable, then the solution is $\{(x,x-1,3x-2):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: $y$ is as free as $z$ is. And you can work out the system to get $x$ free.

Comment: So did I, obviously.

Comment: you're right. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much designate one or more variables to be "free" then solve for the other variables in terms of those.

Your equations are x+ (1/2)y+ (1/2)z= 1/2 and y- (1/3)z= -1/3.  From the second equation, y= (1/3)z- 1/3.  Putting that into the first equation x+ (1/2)((1/3)z- 1/3)+ (1/2)z= x+ (2/3)z- 1/6= 1/2 which reduces to x= 2/3- (2/3)z.  We can take z to be the "free" variable and then calculate x and y for each value of z.  But we could also solve x= 2/3- (2/3)z for z: z= 1- (3/2)x and then have y= (1/3)(1- (3/2)x)- 1/3= -(3/2)x where x is the "free variable".  Or we could solve y- (1/3)z= -1/3 for z: z= 3y+ 1.  Putting that into the first equation. x+ (1/2)y+ (1/2)(3y+ 1)= x+ 2y+ (1/2)= 1/2 or x= -2y so that y is the "free" variable.

The only thing we can say is that this problem has **one** free variable.  *Which* variable is that free variable is a choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can move unknowns to the RHS and declare them free variables to form a solvable system. In your case you will need two equations in two unknowns, hence a single free variable.

$$\begin{cases}x+2y-z=0\\2x+y-z=1\end{cases}$$
 becomes one of

$$\begin{cases}2y-z=-x\\y-z=1-2x\end{cases}$$
or 
$$\begin{cases}x-z=-2y\\2x-z=1-y\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}x+2y=z\\2x+y=1+z.\end{cases}$$

Beware anyway that the LHS equations that you keep must be linearly independent (no problem here).